# $G$ is direct product of $H_1,\ldots,H_k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a direct product of the groups $H_1,\ldots,H_k$, let $K\vartriangleleft G$. Prove that if $Z(G)$ doesn't contain $K$, then there is $i$ such thet $K\cap H_i \neq\{ e \}$ ($e$ is the identity element)

Tried to prove by contradiction, don't have many ideas..
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

proof by contrapositive,

Let $K\cap H_i=e$ for all $i$ .

Notice that if two normal subgroup intersect trivially then they must ommutes with each ather. Thus, elements of $K$ commutes elemets of $H_i$ for all $i$ which means that $K\leq Z(G)$.

Comment: I think $\;K\cap H_i\;\;\forall\,i\iff K=1\;$ , and of course this would mean $\;K\le Z(G)\;$ , but I don't think this is what was meant.

Comment: @Timbuc: $K\cap H_i=e $ for all $i$ does not implies that $K=1$.

Comment: I think it does, @mesel , otherwise there is $\;1\neq(x_1,...,x_k)\in K\implies x_i\neq 1\;$ for some $\;i\;$ $\;\implies K\cap H_i\neq1\;$ . But of course I could be wrong.

Comment: @Timbuc: Let $G=Z_2\times Z_2$ and $H=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ notice that $H$ intersect triviall with both components of product.

Comment: I know this example, which shows that subgroups of a direct product don't have to be the direct product of subgroups of the factors...and it works in this case, too. Thanks, deleting my incorrect answer. Not only that, your answer is crystal clear now. +1

Comment: @Timbuc: You are welocome.

Answer (score 1):

$K$ is non trivial, thus is contains a non-trivial element, then one of the elements in its factorization $(h_1,h_2\dots h_n)$ is not trivial. Let it be $h_i$, then the intersection of $K$ with the subgrouop of elements of the form $(e,e,e \dots h_i, e, e )$ is non trivial (Although this subgroup is not $H_i$).